# How to ensure a RESTful API is backwards compatible?

Tags: api, backwards-compatibility

In my company, we develop an API which is consumed by external customers. We want our API to evolve in a backwards-compatible way without using versions.

We would like to have tests on our side that validate that, whenever our API evolves (e.g. new attributes are added to requests or responses) backwards-compatibility is guaranteed. What is the best way of validating that?

I've had a look at contract-testing (Pact or Spring Cloud Contract) but they seem particularly effective in consumer-driven testing - which is not what we want to do.